# AdMob : Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout

Tags: android, width, admob, adview

I add AdMob by canvas :

```
public void drawAddMob(final Activity a){
a.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
public void run(){
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(a);
ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
adView = new AdView(a, AdSize.BANNER,  "a15140cd49b6e7b");  
adView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(320,50));
AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
adView.loadAd(request);
ll.addView(adView);
ll.draw(canvas);
}});
}
```

but when it's loading i get such error :

```
 W/webcore(347): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
```

and its reloading - request admob one more time and each time i get this error , after 3 times it stop and write "onRecieveAd()" but it doesn't appear on the screen and still befor it i get error